# How to play an AIFF sound file using Erlang?

Tags: audio, erlang, playback, aiff

I am trying to look for a way to play an AIFF file using Erlang.

I have found this [tutorial](http://prog21.dadgum.com/92.html), but it seems to be only about reading the content of the file and not actually playing it.

Comment: I suppose there is no cross-platform solution for this task. What OS do you want to play a sound on?

Comment: On Ubuntu you may use PulseAudio to play sounds. But you'll need to write erlang port program or driver to do that. I haven't found any existing out there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the linux command "play" with "os:cmd" or "ports". It is quite ad-hoc but it is not a very uncommon command and it may do the trick.